# Nose Test Three Versions of the Same Function

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have three different versions of the same function that performs a calculation. Given the same input, all three will produce the same output. However, the difference is that the three functions are implemented differently and might perform better/worse in different situations.

An analogy would be like having 3 different sorting functions. How do I write unit tests using nose test so as to not repeat myself?

```
def sort_a(array):
    """
    sort using and return
    """
    return sorted_array

def sort_b(array):
    """
    sort using and return
    """
    return sorted_array

def sort_c(array):
    """
    sort using and return
    """
    return sorted_array
```

My test might look like this:

```
class TestCore:
    def test_sort_a_positive_vals(self):
        # run test

    def test_sort_a_negative_vals(self):
        # run test

    def test_sort_b_positive_vals(self):
        # run test

    def test_sort_b_negative_vals(self):
        # run test

    def test_sort_c_positive_vals(self):
        # run test

    def test_sort_c_negative_vals(self):
        # run test
```

It feels like there is a lot of redundancy here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [nose-parameterized](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-parameterized/).

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized

def square_exp(x):
    return x**2

def square_mul(x):
    return x*x

class SquareTest(TestCase):    

    @parameterized.expand([(square_exp,), (square_mul,)])
    def test_square(self, square_impl):
        self.assertEqual(square_impl(3), 9)
```

Comment: But this would require adding the nose_parameterized package. Is there a way to do this in nose directly?

Comment: Well, so what?  What's wrong with adding a package?

Comment: Trying to reduce dependencies

Comment: The test/development dependencies don't really matter, you should be keeping those separate from runtime dependencies anyway.

Comment: Are you saying that it is impossible to accomplish this without use nose_parameterized?

Comment: If you could do it directly in nose, then nose_parameterized package wouldn't even exist, would it?  You could just use a for-loop instead, but you wouldn't get multiple independent tests that way.